# MongoDB full text search inside embedded object

Tags: json, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

This is my sample data

```
{
    _id: 123123123,
    author:{
     name : "username"
    },
    data:{
     title : "Hello World"
    }
}
```

And this is my Index command : `db.post.createIndex({"data.title":"text"})`

But when I execute  `db.post.find( { $text: { $search: "Hello" } } )` I get nothing back.

What command should I run to index an embed object inside mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This: `db.post.createIndex({"data.title":"text"})` is the correct command to create a text index on an embedded field.

This: `db.post.find( { $text: { $search: "Hello" } } )` is the correct way of engaging the text index to search for the value `Hello` in the embedded field: `data.title`.

You are doing everything correctly. To verify this, I have taken your document, written it to a collection, created a text index on that collection using the `createIndex()` command you supplied and searched for it using the `find()` command you supplied and that document **is** returned.

So, perhaps the issue is elsewhere. I would suggest that you:

- Confirm that the text index was **definitely** created. You can do this by running `db.post.getIndexes()`, if the text index is present and does cover data.title then you should see something like this in the output from that command:

  ```
  {
      "v" : 2,
      "key" : {
          "_fts" : "text",
          "_ftsx" : 1
      },
      "name" : "data.title_text",
      "ns" : "<your database name>.post",
      "weights" : {
          "data.title" : 1
      },
      "default_language" : "english",
      "language_override" : "language",
      "textIndexVersion" : 3
  }
  ```
- Confirm that there is **definitely** a document with `data.title` containing `Hello`. You can do this by running a simple find: `db.post.find({'data.title':  { $regex:  /Hello/  } })`.
- Confirm that this command: `db.post.find( { $text: { $search: "Hello" } } )` **definitely** uses your text index. You can do this by invoking that command with `.explain()` (e.g. `db.post.find( { $text: { $search: "Hello" } } ).explain()`) and the output should include something like this:

  ```
      "inputStage" : {
          "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
          "inputStage" : {
              "stage" : "TEXT_OR",
              "inputStage" : {
                  "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                  "keyPattern" : {
                      "_fts" : "text",
                      "_ftsx" : 1
                  },
                  "indexName" : "data.title_text",
                  "isMultiKey" : true,
                  "isUnique" : false,
                  "isSparse" : false,
                  "isPartial" : false,
                  "indexVersion" : 2,
                  "direction" : "backward",
                  "indexBounds" : {}
              }
          }
  ```